# ¿como eliminar un usuario de la tabla aspnetusers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, blazor

hola comunidad estoy trabajando con asp.net core 3.1 y blazor he creado un crud el cual ya borra registros pero después me genere un unas tablas de usuarios y roles con identity ahora quiero borrar esos usuarios y lo trato de hacer de la manera en que lo hice en mi crud pero me da un error aquí les dejo mi código para que me ayuden por favor.

aquí tengo mi botón para eliminar usuario:

```
<tbody>
                @foreach (var usuario in Usuarios)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/editar-usuario/@usuario.UserId" class="btn btn-info"><i class="oi oi-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(()=>BorrarUsuario(usuario))"><i class="oi oi-trash"></i> Borrar</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @usuario.Email
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

aquí tengo mi método borrar usuario:

```
private async Task BorrarUsuario(UsuarioDTO usuarioDTO)
{
    string mensajeconfirmacion = $"¿Desea borrar este usuario: {usuarioDTO.Email}?";
    var confirmado = await JS.Confirm("Confirmar", mensajeconfirmacion, IJSRuntimeExtensionMethods.TipoMensajeSweetAlert.question);
    if (confirmado)
    {
        var responseHttp = await repositorio.Delete($"/api/Usuarios/{usuarioDTO.UserId}");            

        if (responseHttp.Error)
        {
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError(await responseHttp.GetBody());
        }
        else
        {
            //esto para volver a cargar los registros
            await Cargar();
        }
    }
}
```

este es mi petición en el controlador:

```
[HttpDelete("UserId")]
        public async Task<ActionResult>Delete(UsuarioDTO usuarioDTO)
        {   
            var usuario = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(usuarioDTO.UserId);
            await userManager.DeleteAsync(usuario);
            return NoContent();
        }
```

este es el error que me arroja en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí esta mi código de como edite al usuario lo que hago es que le asigno y le quito un rol al usuario es mi pagina de editarrol.razor:

```
 private async Task AsignarRol()
        {
            await EditarRol("api/Usuarios/asignarRol");
        }

        private async Task RemoverRol()
        {
            await EditarRol("api/Usuarios/removerRol");
        }


    private async Task EditarRol(string url)
        {      
            if (rolSeleccionado == "0")
            {               
                await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError("Debe seleccionar un rol");
                return;
            }

            var rolDTO = new EditarRolDTO() { RoleId = rolSeleccionado, UserId = UserId };

            var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post<EditarRolDTO>(url, rolDTO);

            if (httpResponse.Error)
            {
                await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError(await httpResponse.GetBody());
            }
            else
            {
                await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeExitoso("Operación realizada");
            }
        }
```

y aquí esta el código de mi usuariocontroller el cual es consumido con lo de arriba:

```
[HttpPost("asignarRol")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AsignarRolUsuario(EditarRolDTO editarRolDTO)
{

    var usuario = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(editarRolDTO.UserId);
    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(usuario, editarRolDTO.RoleId);
    return NoContent();
}

[HttpPost("removerRol")]
public async Task<ActionResult> RemoverUsuarioRol(EditarRolDTO editarRolDTO)
{
    var usuario = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(editarRolDTO.UserId);
    await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(usuario, editarRolDTO.RoleId);
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: ¿La edición de usuarios te funciona correctamente, de ser así, podrías incluir el código de como haces la modificación?

Comment: en la edición de usuario solo edito su tipo de rol no edito su usuario ni contraseña , pero no encuentro el error en el endpoint o en la ruta que es lo que me marca en la consola algo esta mal ahí

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código de la edición para comparar respecto al borrado?

Comment: listo acabo de añadir el codigo de editar roles de usuario

Comment: He creado una sala para hablar mejor https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106514/como-eliminar-un-usuario-de-la-tabla-aspnetusers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu endpoint para el **delete** espera un id, un guid/string el cual usa para buscar el usuario que deseas eliminar

```
[HttpDelete("{Id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult>Delete(string Id)
{
     usuario = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);
     userManager.DeleteAsync(usuario);
     NoContent();
}
```

Comment: excelente muchas gracias por tu ayuda , ya funciono :)